# WooCommerce & WPML: Can't get prices in selected currency in custom ajax call

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system, wpml

I added `WPML` plugin to my `Woocommerce` shop. Most parts of shop is custom coded by me and everything works fine. At the moment shop have several languages and each language have own currency. Default currency is `EUR`.

When I change language shop currency change too, so prices correctly changes by selected language and currency.

The problems appears in `ajax` calls. When I filter products in `WP_Query()` I only get prices in default currency `EUR`, if filter products not for `ajax` purpose then results give me correct currency.

p.s. I'm pretty new in `Wordpress`, but not in programming

Function which handle `ajax` calls and where problem appear

```
function do_search()
{
    check_ajax_referer('main_nonce', 'security');

    $search_query = sanitize_text_field($_POST['search_query']);
    $reults = array();

    $args = array(
        's' => $search_query,
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Check is query not a empty string
    if ($search_query === '') {
        wp_send_json(array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'results' => $reults,
        ));
        return;
    }

    if ($query->have_posts()) {

        // Get all rezults data
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();

            // $product = wc_get_product($query->post->ID);
            $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
            $price_html = $product->get_price_html();

            array_push($reults, array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'price' => $price_html,
                'permalink' => get_permalink(),
                'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail'),
            ));
        }

        // Return results data
        wp_send_json(array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'results' => $reults,
        ));
    } else {
        // Return no results message
        wp_send_json(array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'results' => $reults,
        ));
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_do_search', 'do_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_do_search', 'do_search');
```

Comment: You should better ask the very nice and efficient WPML support for that...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that I had to add filter to `function.php` that allow to get correct currency in `ajax` call.

```
function load_multi_currency_in_ajax($load)
{
    return true;
}

add_filter('wcml_load_multi_currency_in_ajax', 'load_multi_currency_in_ajax', 10, 1);
```